# Ender 3 power supply top screw isn't tightening

Tags: creality-ender-3, power-supply

I was trying to fasten the top screw on the power supply of my Ender 3, but it won't fasten. So, I took the screw out and found something like a little yellow ring stuck onto it. I think it broke because I may have over fastened it, but I didn't tighten too much... Is this the "thread" of the hole? Is it supposed to be so fragile?

[image: Img of ring]

Comment: If you could [edit] in a photo that would help in finding a solution.

Comment: Just added the picture :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you've stripped the thread by overtorquing the fastener.

Your options are to use a slightly larger fastener and drill/tap the larger hole for that bigger thread.  And don't confuse the screws next time you open this connector.

The little yellow ring might be a retainer so the screw is held *captive* in the part, or it could be a load spreading washer, or a soft area to soak up vibration and prevent buzzing/rattling and resonance.